# Grab all frames from IP camera

Tags: camera, ip-camera, video-recording

I have a Sony IPELA snc-ch180 camera. It's a network camera.
Is there a way I can save all frames from the live images onto my hard drive?

Any idea what software can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to check the camera reference and find out supported protocols, some of which are likely to be well known ones (alternatively, you reverse engineer them using network sniffer). Then you implement a client that connects to the camera and receives video stream. Having it received you parse it, decode it into frames, decompress/recompress if necessary and save to hard drive.